# Return table A if condition met; else, return table B

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server.  I have 3 temp tables: #t1, #t2, and #t3.  They're all identical in schema.  If some condition is met, I need to set #t1 to #t2; else, I need to set #t1 to #t3.  How can I achieve this?  I have tried an if-else statement, but it doesn't like the second INTO statement.

```
IF @a = 1
    SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM #t2
ELSE
    SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM #t3
;
```

Comment: You're getting a compiler error?

Comment: I suggest that your approach has taken a detour. "Identical in schema" - especially for temp tables - suggests you have over-complicated your code and will wind up making things more difficult for yourself. And stop applying the pattern of <select ... into #x ...> without a really good reason.

Comment: @SMor   Why is the <select ... into #x> pattern bad in general?  I work in Power BI and have to create a lot of complex queries down in SQL Server (as opposed to in Power BI's transformation language, i.e., M).  I used to use CTEs a lot for my queries, but I found that the <select ... into #x> pattern is much faster.

Comment: Much faster than what? Just `create table` with the correct schema and do `insert ... select...`

Comment: @skyline01 You MIGHT have a good reason then. But there is nothing in your post to indicate that you thought about doing your "work" as a single query or that you use powerbi or that you did anything beyond apply a pattern - one that I see over and over and over for relatively simple queries. Quite frankly, applying ANY pattern is bad if there is no thought given to whether the pattern is both useful and efficient. There is a cost to creating and populating a temp table. I also note the use of "select *" - another bad habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a good practice but this ought to get around the error.

```
select * into #t1 from (
    select * from #t2 where @a = 1 union all
    select * from #t3 where @a <> 1 or @a is null
) t;
```

The better idea is to create the table explicitly and add rows via `insert`. You also should evaluate why the use of such identical tables is necessary at all.

Comment: I guess the "select * from" are mistaken. They are from #t2 and #t3

Comment: Good catch. I was typing on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable with the name of the table with the condition, and then use the EXEC function to use the name of table as variable. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(3)

IF (@a = 1) SET @tb = '#t2'
ELSE SET @tb = '#t3'

EXEC('SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM ' + @tb)
```